# Error in program

Tags: java

```
//This program determines if the input string is a palindrome
import java.util.*;//importing all the methods from java.util class

import static java.lang.System.out;
public class Pallindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        String pallindrome;
        out.println("Enter a string: ");
        pallindrome= input.nextLine();
        ArrayList<String> pall= new ArrayList<String>();
        buildAL(pall, pallindrome);
        display(pall);
        if(isPalendrome(pall))
            out.println(pallindrome + " is a pallindrome");
        else
            out.println(pallindrome + " is not a pallindrome");


    }

    static void display(ArrayList<String> arr1){    //this method is for displaying the array list
        for(int i=0; i<arr1.size();i++)
            out.print(arr1.get(i));
        out.println();
        }

    static void buildAL(ArrayList<String> arr2, String word){   //this is for building the array with the entered word
        for(int i=0;i<arr2.size();i++)
            arr2.add(word.charAt(i)+ "");

    }

    static Boolean isPalendrome(ArrayList<String> arr3){    //it will test if the word is pallindrome
        ArrayList<String> rarr3= new ArrayList<String>();
        rarr3.addAll(arr3);
        Collections.reverse(rarr3);
        for(int i=0;i<rarr3.size();i++)
            if(!(rarr3.get(i).equals(arr3.get(i))))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

When I run this code it shows the same output. please point out the error.

Comment: You need to tell us the error for us to tell you why, but you know `StringBuilder` has a `reverse()` method right? Also, the word is palindrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what the problem is but your for loop doesnt over the letters in `word` as the termination condition is based on the empty `List` size passed to the `buildAL` method. Replace

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr2.size(); i++)
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
static void buildAL(ArrayList<String> arr2, String word){   
for(int i=0;i<arr2.size();i++)
    arr2.add(word.charAt(i)+ "");
}
```

`arr2.size()` is `0` as you don't have any element in the list. Either add the `word` to the list or do `word.length()` in `for` loop.

Also, if I have to do the same thing I would do something like -

After reading the string from the scanner, Simply do

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("your String");
if ("yourString".equals(sb.reverse().toString())) {
   //or you can use equalsIgnoreCase also if that fits your requirement
   //its a palindrome
}  //Otherwise, not.
```